# show another image when image is not available

Tags: php

i have a code which gets images from a database. I need to tell it to to display another image (which says no image available) if an image is not found. How would I do this????

Your suggestions would be very much appreciated

```
<a class="thumbimage" href="<?PHP mrd("$MyProductTitle", "$row[LID]", "$_GET[category]", "$rowxxx[MR]", "index.php?page=detail"); ?>"><img src="images/thumb/<?php echo "$row[IMAGENAME]"; ?>.jpg" border="1" /></a>
```

Comment: [Do *some* research](http://au2.php.net/is_file), this is trivial.

Comment: I agree with @Marty and its also a dublicate for sure!

Comment: dear marty and axel ok the me the answer if you know

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
    $currentImage = "images/thumb/".$row[IMAGENAME].".jpg";
    if(!file_exists($currentImage))
    {
        $currentImage = "PATH_TO_IMAGE_UNAVAILABLE";
    }
?>

<a class="thumbimage" href="<?PHP mrd("$MyProductTitle", "$row[LID]", "$_GET[category]", "$rowxxx[MR]", "index.php?page=detail"); ?>"><img src="<?=$currentImage?>" border="1" /></a>
```

Comment: see complete code

    <?PHP
//---------------------------------------------------------------------                                
$filename = "$svr_rootscript/product_images/thumb/$row[IMAGENAME].jpg"; 
if (file_exists($filename)) {
//---------------------------
?>

<td valign="top" ><a class="thumbimage" href="<?PHP mrd("$MyProductTitle", "$row[LID]", "$_GET[category]", "$rowxxx[MR]", "index.php?page=detail"); ?>"><img src="product_images/thumb/<?php echo "$row[IMAGENAME]"; ?>.jpg" border="1" title="<?php echo "$row[TITLE]"; ?>"  alt="<?php echo "$row[TITLE]"; ?>" /></a></td>
<?PHP } ?>

Answer (score 0):

You can use onerror attribute.

Replace the error image (3331913_orig.gif) with yours error image on the code below:

```
<img src="{some_error_src}" onerror="this.onerror=null;this.src='http://availableservicesllc.weebly.com/uploads/2/2/3/9/22390468/3331913_orig.gif'">
```

Click [here](https://jsfiddle.net/k17mm6a9/) to see this example